# My Unity game's timers are messed up when it's played in the browser, and the tab/page is out of focus?

Tags: unity, browser

I've made some **timer** classes, which just basically:

- hold an **elapsed time** value,
- and when they are **updated, Time.deltaTime is added**,
- and their update is called in **MonoBehaviours' Updates**.

**And an issue appeared:**

- On one machine with **Firefox**, **streaming** my game, the tab was **out of focus** for 30 seconds,

  - And the **timers stopped after a while**.
  - The time after which the timers stopped, **always varied**.
- On one machine with **Firefox**, tabs out focus didn't do much thing, but **browser out of focus** did.

  - On every run, the **effect was random**, sometimes time stopped, sometimes slow, etc.
- On my machine, both with **Chrome** and **Firefox**, both with **swtching tabs** and **switching windows**...

  - Time **went at like 30% speed** when out of focus, and when switched back, everything **was normal again**.

Why?

Comment: From what I've seen, having an application out of focus has different behaviour on different platforms. Have you though about not having anything run in the background, but instead when your game comes back in focus to check how much time has elapsed and add that to the timer?

Comment: That would solve it, but I don't want to implement platform specific solutions yet. I thought that maybe there is a built in solution for this.

Comment: That's what I meant, your current implementation is platform specific, as there is no guarantee what is going to run when your game is out of focus (as you've spotted yourself). A platform-agnostic way would be to save the current time when your game pauses, then when it resumes take the current time again and compare it with that time, and see how long your game has been out of focus (regardless of platform)

Comment: I mean I don't want to implement something like "if platform == browser". (I only want to do this in browsers). But yeah, now that I think about it, maybe I should just implement this generally. If the window loses focus, even if it's standalone, I pause the game.

Comment: Well, if you are looking for some functionality that is different on browsers, you have to right platform-specific code. I would suggest against that, and have the game pause even on native builds.

Comment: @TomTsagk Okay, thanks!